# Predict "user-input" reviews with Naive Bayes trained model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, user-input, text-classification, naivebayes

I am using a dataset with textual Yelp restaurant reviews and their "star" rating. 
My data is a df and looks like this:

```
Textual Review           Numeric rating
"super cool restaurant"  5
"horrible experience"    1
```

I have built the MultinomialNB model which predicts the "star" (1-stands for negative, 5 stands for positive; using only these two categories) for the review.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from textblob import TextBlob
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
import numpy

df = pd.read_csv('YELP_rev.csv')
#subsetting only the reviews on the extreme sides of the rating
df_class = df[(df['Numeric rating'] ==1) | (df['Numeric rating'] == 5)]

X = df_class['Textual review']
y = df_class['Numeric rating']
vectorizer=CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=101)

nb = MultinomialNB()
#fiting the model with X_train, y_train
nb.fit(X_train, y_train)
#doing preditions
pred = nb.predict(X_test)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, pred))



precision    recall  f1-score   support

           1       0.43      0.33      0.38         9
           5       0.90      0.93      0.92        61

   micro avg       0.86      0.86      0.86        70
   macro avg       0.67      0.63      0.65        70
weighted avg       0.84      0.86      0.85        70
```

**What I'm trying to do is to predict "star" rating for the user provided restaurant review.** Here are my attempts:

```
test_review = input("Enter a review:")  

def input_process(text):
    nopunc = [char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation]
    nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)
    return [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')]

new_x=vectorizer.transform(input_process(test_review))
test_review_rate = nb.predict(new_x)
print(test_review_rate)
```

I am not sure whether the output that I am getting is correct since I get an array of scores. **Can someone help me interpret these scores?** **Do I just take the average and that will be my "star"rating for the review?**

```
>>Enter a review:We had dinner here for my birthday in Stockholm. The restaurant was very popular, so I would advise you book in advance.Blahblah
#my output
>>[5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 1 5 1 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
 5 5 5 5]
```

ps I realize that the sample data is poor and my model is biased towards positive ratings!
Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Please include explicitly your imports

Comment: @desertnaut done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `join` your words back into a single string. Right now the output from your `input_process` function is a list of words, so your model is interpreting each word as a separate input sample, which is why you are getting a score for each **word** in your review, instead of one score for the whole text.

Some changes in your code:

```
def input_process(text):
    # Something you can try for removing punctuations
    translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    nopunc = text.translate(translator)
    words = [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')]
    # Join the words back and return as a string
    return ' '.join(words)

# vectorizer.transform takes a list as input
# You will have to pass your single string input as a list
new_x=vectorizer.transform([input_process(test_review)])
```

Comment: can't believe I missed that! thanks so much @panktijk!